# How can i disable/cancel setTimeOut when i mouseover && mouseout in specific areas?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, jquery

i have a **simple horizontal menu** with four choices.
When i mouseover a div (e.g. div A), its child appears and
when i mouseout that specific div, its child disappears.

I have placed a setTimeOut function for mouseover (it is about 300).

In some specific conditions i would like to disable setTimeout

**1.** when i **mouseout div A**  and **i mouseover div B**, i would **not** like to have that delay,
and i would like just to show the childDiv of B

**2.** when i **mouseout div B**  and i **mouseover div C**, i would **not** like to have that delay,
and i would like just to show the childDiv of C

But how can i achieve that??

It's just that i have a series of events:
(a simple algorithm)

```
If(mouseout(divA) && mouseover(divB))
   {
   disable setTimeOut;
   show(ChildDivB);  //with no delay
   }
else If(mouseout(divB) && mouseover(divC))
   {
   disable setTimeOut;
   show(ChildDivC);  //with no delay
   }

   }
```

Generally, when i **mouseover && mouseout** in "foo" div, (foo is the div that contains all divs) the settimeout shall be disabled.

Can this be done in jquery??

**My code is as follows:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
    .myDiv {
        border:1px solid red;
        height:30px;
        width:100px;
        float:left;
        }
    .myDivChild {
        display:none;
        width:300px;
        height:300px;

    }   
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="foo" style="background-color:#3300FF;width:900px;height:30px;margin-top:100px;">
    <div class="myDiv" style="background-color:red;margin-left:100px">A
        <div class="myDivChild" style="background-color:red">
            Child Div A
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" style="background-color:yellow">B
        <div class="myDivChild" style="background-color:yellow">
            Child Div B
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" style="background-color:green">C
        <div class="myDivChild" style="background-color:green">
            Child Div C
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" style="background-color:#00CCCC">D
        <div class="myDivChild" style="background-color:#00CCCC">
            Child Div D
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var interval;


    $('.foo > div').hover(function(){
                                    var $showDiv =     $(this).find('div');         
                                    interval = setTimeout(function(){
                                                                    $showDiv.show();
                                                                    },300);
                                    },
                        function(){
                                clearTimeout(interval);
                                $(this).find('div').hide();
                                });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this question solved or not?

Answer (score 7):

Assign a variable then clear it like this:

`var myInterval=setTimeout(...);`

To disable:

`clearTimeout(myInterval);`

Be careful that the variable assigned to the setTimeout has scope where you clear the timeout.
Also, each variable holds only one interval. If you overwrite it it will not clear the previous timeout. (unless it's an array or object with multiple keys/properties in which case you cannot clear the whole array/object, you need to loop through them and clear each one at a time.)

Comment: he already had that much.  the event handlers are the real question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do something like

```
If(mouseout(divA) && mouseover(divB))
```

because these are events, not variables. What you need to do is record a state of the application and then react to this state. For example, in the event handler function of mouseOut, set a variable

```
lastMouseOut = this;
```

Then, in the event handler function of mouseOver, you can do your comparison:

```
if ((lastMouseOut==divA) && (this==divB)) {...}
```

Make sure lastMouseOut is a global variable, not a local one in the handler function.

Comment: Travelboy: I think he was trying to make it simpler to understand what he needs rather than write proper code. Not sure though.

Comment: Yes Jared, thanks, I corrected that. I wrote too much Pascal when I was young :)

Comment: I wrote a simple algorithm to describe the problem, i don't use that in jquery,just to understand in simple words what i would like to achieve

Answer (score 1):

This is what I worked out as an example:

**CSS**

```
#menu li {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu ul {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="one" class="mainMenu">Menu 1
        <ul>
            <li>Submenu 1</li>
            <li>Submenu 2</li>
            <li>Submenu 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="one"class="mainMenu">Menu 2
        <ul>
            <li>Submenu 1</li>
            <li>Submenu 2</li>
            <li>Submenu 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="three"class="mainMenu">Menu 3
        <ul>
            <li>Submenu 1</li>
            <li>Submenu 2</li>
            <li>Submenu 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $('.mainMenu').hover(
        function(){doMenu(this)},
        function(){undoMenu(this)}
    );
});

function doMenu(el){
    switch (el.id) {
        case 'one':
        case 'two':
            $('ul', el).show();
        break;
        default:
            var menuTimeout = setTimeout(function(){$('ul', el).show()}, 300);
            $.data($('#menu'), 'menuTimeout', menuTimeout);
    }
}

function undoMenu() {
    $('#menu ul').hide();
    cancelTimeout($.data($('#menu'), 'menuTimeout'));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XJhLD/

Comment: Thanks for the code,i run the code but there is a delay only when i mouseover menu3 and i need in others too,only when i mouseover and mouseout in specific divs the settimeout shall be disabled

Comment: @programmer - You have to look at how the code works. The ones you want no delay on, add a case by the ID; all others will fall through to the default case.

Answer (score -1):

First off, *are you sure that you want a dropdown menu at all*? Since mouseless devices are very common today, like an iPad, you will at least want a fallback solution. That being said, I can say that [I also struggled with this issue](http://thesyntheticfamily.com/) (see their main menu) about a year ago.

Do not reinvent the wheel like I did if you don't have to. Have you tried searching for a small JS plugin/library? You may want to use the jQuery [hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) for the delay stuff.

Comment: I have seen that plugin again, but instead of using a plugin i would like to try it more,thanks

Comment: @Betamos - I think the comment about mouseless devices is interesting. Do you have any more information?

Comment: @Jared Do you mean information about web development for mouseless devices?

Comment: @Betamos - Well, not necessarily. Something (blog post?) that describes the differences inherent between mouse and mouseless navigation or something, with maybe some guidelines to follow. I think that particular issue is one that will grow exponentially in the future (with the adoption of devices), and I'm not sure web developers are really prepared.

Comment: @Jared Indeed, many web applications depends on mouse navigation in one way or another. I have read several articles related to it.[Thoughts on Flash](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/) (Fifth point) is kind of related.

Comment: @Betamos - There has to be something out there which deals with the developmental hurdles inherent in developing for both touch- and mouse-based devices.